# Can ::after pseudo elements be removed inside media queries?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Is there an easy way to remove an `::after` pseudo element inside of a media query?

For example can I completely remove this `::after` pseudo element when the browser width falls below 980px?  Or should I do it the old fashioned way and hide the original class and display a new class when the browser width shrinks below 980px?  How would a professional solve this?

```
.navigation_unit > a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: .0625rem;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,238);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest option is to set the pseudo element's [`content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) value to `none` inside of the media query. In doing so, the pseudo element won't be rendered.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation_unit > a::after {
    content: none;
  }
}
```

As stated by the relevant specification, the values `none` or `normal` would result in the pseudo element no being generated.

> [**12.2 The 'content' property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content)
>
> `none` - The pseudo-element is not generated.
>
> `normal` - Computes to `none` for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Here is a basic example demonstrating this:

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Psuedo-element... ';
  color: #f00;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  p::before {
    content: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Resize this window to less than 600px</p>
```

Comment: Does that actually work? I've never seen `content: none;` before.

Comment: `content: none;` "**none** The pseudo-element is not generated." brilliant solution!

Comment: @JakeParis - Yeah, it works, see [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/kux49c8L/) I added for reference.

Comment: @JoshCrozier We use CSS3 but all of the links point to the css2.1 or css2.2 spec.  I never really understood why that was.  Do the numbers not match up between what the W3 publishes and what we use?

Comment: @DR01D - I usually link to the CSS2 specifications because they are still relevant and they are easier to find most of the time. Some of the specifications are definitely out of date, however a majority of the core concepts in CSS2 are still completely applicable in CSS3 (otherwise they would be breaking backwards-compatibility). Often times the only difference is the addition of new details. [Here is a link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#content-property) to the relevant CSS3 `content` spec, as you can see, it is much more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough mobile-first solution:

```
.navigation_unit a:after {
   ...
   /* everything except content: '' */
}

@media (min-width:980px) {
    .navigation_unit > a:after {
        content: '';
    }
}
```